# Select same length of subarrays by evenly spacing in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python and stackoverflow and I'm working on a project that deal with manually created arrays with different length.

```
path = '/home/Documents/Noise'
files = glob.glob(path + '/*.txt')
data_noise = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', header=None)
    df = df.values
    m,n = df.shape
    df = np.reshape(df,m)
    data_noise.append(df)
```

I create a list `data_noise` to store numpy arrays, each array has different length `m`. I want to select subarrays from each array so that they have same length, say, 100. But instead of selecting the first 100 elements or the last 100 in each array, I want to evenly space and select in each array.

For example, for a length 300 array, I need elements indexed by 0,3,6,9,... and for a length 500 array, I need elements indexed by 0,5,10,15,...

How do I modify my code to do that?

Comment: Something like `np.linspace(0, len(the_array), 100)` to get the indices? You can also force the dtype of the output to `int` to be used as indices.

Comment: @roganjosh I add a new line in the loop `index = np.linspace(0, m, 100).astype(int)` seems the last the index is always the length of the array, which is out of bounds for axis.

Comment: That is that point at which you should [consult the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) since the solution to that issue is provided there.

Comment: @roganjosh that for sure helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not numpy, but in general Python this should work.

```
distance = 100 / m
sub_list = df[0::distance]
```

Provided you add some checks and possibly rounding.